# Regular expression to extract any 4 digit number starting beginning with 5 from a text file using python

Tags: python, regex

I am using the follwoing to extract any 4 digit number starting beginning with 5 from a text file using python:

```
regex = re.compile("^5\d{3}")
```

and this apparently looks only at the beginning of a line and doesn't look further until the end of the line to find the matches.

So for a sample string of "At this period by adding 52000 more particles we reched the value of 5810 threads per molecule." it shows no match.

What is wrong with my regular expression?

Comment: `^` anchors it to the start of the string.

Comment: Thanks, but now it finds two matches "52000" and "5810", although it should only find 4 digit numbers.

Comment: You need do indicate that there should be a non-digit character after the 3 digits: `5\d{3}[^\d]`

Comment: But I don't want to copy the space character following the digit. Nor any other character.

Comment: try this `\s(5[\d]{3})\s`

Comment: It marks the leading and the tailing space with the value " 5810 ".

Comment: Try using word boundaries `\b5\d{3}\b` https://regex101.com/r/whcunu/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`regex = re.compile(r"\b(5\d{3})\b")` is more exact

Answer (score 0):

Just add a whitespace check to the regex expression

```
regex = re.compile(r'(5\d{3})(?=\s|$)')
```

This makes sure the number starts with 5 wherever in the text, has 3 subsequent numbers and has a whitespace character or end of string in front of it and return just the four digits.

Comment: does this work if the string ends after the fourth digit?

Comment: That was a great point, edited accordingly. It now uses a lookahead to check if either has a whitespace or its end of string

Comment: Found a match without additional charachters!

Comment: So, working? You can always test it here: [link](https://regex101.com/r/bc3Med/1)

Answer (score 0):

this regex will capture any 4 digit number starting with a 5 that has no beginning or trailing characters

```
^5\d{3}$
```

see it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/2Yk9Qm/1)

code:

```py
regex = re.compile(r'^5\d{3}$')
```

Comment: No match found.